# Remove duplicates based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have this table, and i would like a SELECT to exclude the lines marked. The general rule would be:

- IF there are two or more lines where the controlname AND brandname AND grouptypes columns are equal
- THEN keep the row where groupname is NOT 'Keine Zuordnung'.

> ```
> CONTROLNAME   BRANDNAME   GROUPTYPES    GROUPNAME
> ECU           AUDI        VERNETZER         1
> ECU           AUDI        VERNETZER     Keine zuordnung    <--THIS
> ECU           AUDI        FUSI          Keine zuordnung    <--THIS
> ECU           AUDI        FUSI              2
> ECU2          AUDI        FACHANWENDER  Keine zuordnung
> ECU3          AUDI        FACHANWENDER  Keine zuordnung
> ```

Can i have a little help with this please? 
Thank you!

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, not images

Comment: Do you want avoid to SELECT the "duplicate", or do you want to DELETE the "duplicate" from the table?

Comment: What should be the result (regardless of whether you need "`DELETE`" or just "`SELECT` but exclude.") - so, what should be the result if there are duplicate rows like you explained, but ALL the duplicates have `'Keine zuordnung'` as GROUPNAME? Delete (or exclude) all of them? Or keep exactly one copy and delete (or exclude) the other(s)?

Comment: @mathguy All duplicate rows have 'Keine Zuordnung' as GROUPNAME. I need to select only the ones that are duplicate AND their GROUPNAME is NOT 'Keine Zuordnung' + the ones that are not duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by  controlname, brandname, grouptypes) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1 or groupname <> 'Keine Zuordnung';
```

It uses a window function to get the count and then a `where` for your logic.